# How do you free a wrapped C++ object when associated Javascript object is garbage collected in V8?

Tags: javascript, c++, v8

V8's documentation explains [how to create a Javascript object that wraps a C++ object](http://code.google.com/apis/v8/embed.html#dynamic). The Javascript object holds on to a pointer to a C++ object instance. My question is, let's say you create the C++ object on the heap, how can you get a notification when the Javascript object is collected by the gc, so you can free the heap allocated C++ object?

Comment: The supplied hotlink is (probably long-)dead. A plausible guess at what it might have contained is: https://v8.dev/docs/embed#templates

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The trick is to create a `Persistent` handle (second bullet point from the linked-to API reference:  "`Persistent` handles are not held on a stack and are deleted only when you specifically remove them. ... Use a persistent handle when you need to keep a reference to an object for more than one function call, or when handle lifetimes do not correspond to C++ scopes."), and call `MakeWeak()` on it, passing a callback function that will do the necessary cleanup ("A persistent handle can be made weak, using `Persistent::MakeWeak`, to trigger a callback from the garbage collector when the only references to an object are from weak persistent handles." -- that is, when all "regular" handles have gone out of scope and when the garbage collector is about to delete the object).

The `Persistent::MakeWeak` method signature is:

```
void MakeWeak(void* parameters, WeakReferenceCallback callback);
```

Where `WeakReferenceCallback` is defined as a pointer-to-function taking two parameters:

```
typedef void (*WeakReferenceCallback)(Persistent<Object> object,
                                      void* parameter);
```

These are found in the v8.h header file distributed with V8 as the public API.

You would want the function you pass to `MakeWeak` to clean up the `Persistent<Object>` object parameter that will get passed to it when it's called as a callback.  The `void* parameter` parameter can be ignored (or the `void* parameter` can point to a C++ structure that holds the objects that need cleaning up):

```
void CleanupV8Point(Persistent<Object> object, void*)
{
    // do whatever cleanup on object that you're looking for
    object.destroyCppObjects();
}

Parameter<ObjectTemplate> my_obj(ObjectTemplate::New());

// when the Javascript part of my_obj is about to be collected
// we'll have V8 call CleanupV8Point(my_obj)
my_obj.MakeWeak(NULL, &CleanupV8Point);
```

Comment: How do you do that for a Local<Object>?   I'm trying to do it from within my constructor FunctionTemplate.   I can't figure out a syntax that doesn't yell at me.  Tried .MakeWeak but that doesn't exist, tried Persistent::New, but it wanted a pointer to my object and my compiler wouldn't let me create a pointer to a local object.

Comment: @xaxxon: I'll be the first to admit that I don't have any experience with the V8 Javascript engine (I happened to be able to find the answer to this question from the documentation six years ago).  I **think** the answer to your question is the example on https://developers.google.com/v8/embed?csw=1#dynamic , but it's also possible that you have a question worth asking on its own.

Comment: Thanks.   I did eventually figure it out.   https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/v8/src/d8.cc&l=1064 starting around line 1400

Answer (score 0):

In general, if a garbage-collected language can hold references to resources outside of the language engine (files, sockets, or in your case C++ objects), you should provide a 'close' method to release that resource ASAP, no point waiting until the GC thinks it's worthwhile to destroy your object.

it gets worse if your C++ object is memory-hungry and the garbage-collected object is just a reference: you might allocate thousands of objects, and the GC only sees a few KB's of tiny objects, not enough to trigger collection; while the C++ side is struggling with tens of megabytes of stale objects.

Comment: That's why there's the function V8::AdjustAmountOfExternalAllocatedMemory()... This way you can tell V8 that your object is hungry... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Do all your work in some closed scope (of object or function).
Then you can safely remove the C++ object when you went out of scope. GC doesn't check pointers for existence of pointed objects.